# Need to send SMS to 11K people at once but don't know in advance how much $ to have in balance?

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api, bulksms

I have a python script which sends to all 11K people an SMS at once, they are from all sorts of countries.
I don't want to have money left over in my balance as I won't be doing that again.
Problem it's too difficult to estimate the cost as the people are from 190 different countries.
I know there is Auto-recharge which is enabled for me, but the issue is that it's sending all messages at once, so I do not think auto-recharge will work as it needs to recharge inside milliseconds.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try batching strategies, since most numbers can't process more than 10 SMS/second (1 SMS/second for NA numbers) anyhow (anything more will just get queued), so 11k messages would take ~18 mins anyhow.

So split your pool into 5 batches of ~2k messages, and see how much the first 3 batches cost, which would inform how much money to load for batches 4 & 5.

**NOTE:** running out of money mid-batch would need to be adequately handled, too.

Sending costs will vary by [destination] country, but these rates are published, e.g. [US - 0.75 cents/msg](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us), [India - 1.75 cents/msg](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/in), [UK - 4 cents/msg](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/gb), etc.

Then the problem becomes one of [parsing out country codes from your target numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259347/extract-the-country-code-from-mobile-number/42983438) if they're not already split (e.g. +18005551234 vs. +1 8005551234).

Comment: I like your strategy. I will do that. Thanks. I did not undertstand the last paragraph you wrote though, could you explain differently?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I’ve updated the last paragraph with more concrete examples!